# Mysql 1820 error when create procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

I faced one issue when use mysql to create procedures.
I used "root@localhost" to create the procedure. the command executed successfully.
After that I remove procedure A and want to use "root@127.0.0.1" to create A and then faced the error: 1820 - You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement.

Actually I have set the password for that, but still error.
And other procedure used "root@127.0.0.1" are all successfully without any error. The issue only faced on A.

As I know this error usually found on create DB. but this time... :(

Anybody can help me? Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

Right from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html):

> After an account's password has been expired, all operations performed
>   in subsequent connections to the server using the account result in an
>   error until the user issues a SET PASSWORD statement to establish a
>   new account password:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1;
> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement
>
> mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT 1;
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

Comment: hola, I can understand your comment. But I have tried this way, it was not useful.. very strange.

Comment: Guessing from your answer, I suspect you didn't log in with the affected user.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the issue was resolved with below statement:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

SET PASSWORD FOR 'some_user'@'some_host' = PASSWORD('newpwd');

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++